# elcipse shortcut interference with windows 7 desktop rotation

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, key-binding

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> in eclipse ide, for copying lines.

Recently, I started using windows 7, and the above key combination is not being detected by eclipse, but rather picked up by windows 7 which rotates the complete screen upside down.

My eclipse settings shows the key bindings which have not being altered so far.

[image: eclipse key]

How to stop windows from detecting this key combination and make sure, it is taken by eclipse ?

Comment: This is definitely a graphics driver shortcut/hot-key, and the settings app provided should be capable of disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing you can turn off from within Windows is the windows key (and it's either on or off).

A keyboard re-mapper may suffice though? http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows

Also, this may not be an issue with Windows, but with the graphic card. Are you able to disable shortcut keys in the graphic card app (if one exists): [source](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/143325-Windows-7-shortcut-%28CTRL-ALT-Down%29-overrides-application-hotkey)